# Creating column that is a combination of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a SQL Server table where I have a code column (`nvarchar`) and an ID column (`int`). I am trying to create a third column that takes the code and combines it with the ID to make a column but I'm unsure how to do this in T-SQL.

I've seen it done in access before - with the data type being calculation.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: it is call [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD ThirdColumn AS Code + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED;
```

For more info - check out the [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) on computed columns in SQL Server.